# Unable to send cross domain post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Hello i am trying to post a form data via `$.post` but getting the following error.[image] but when I run this URL manually, it works fine.

Code is:

```
$.post(
                    'http://dev.mydoamin/capture/' + ip + '/1',
                    $('form#frm1').serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        var parsedJson = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    }
            );
```

Comment: Check out this SO question here:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: Or may be this link http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

It's a Cross-domain.
jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'http://dev.mydoamin/capture/' + ip + '/1',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     data: $('form#frm1').serialize(),
     success:function(data){
         var parsedJson = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     }    
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$arr = array("return_array");
$arr['name'] = "response";
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($arr).");";
?>
```

Comment: now its not showing the request being sent to the URL :(